# Can't upload to VMWare vCenter 6.7 datastore due to certificate, OSX

Tags: macos, certificate, vcenter

Using HTML5 webclient in updated Chrome and Firefox.  Using vCenter 6.7 with self signed certificate.  When trying to upload a file, it gives the error unsupported due to untrusted certificate.  How do I go about uploading files?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, answer for reference:

For vCenter 6.7, to upload files using web client , you need to go to main landing page(before you enter the HTML5 client), on bottom right, download the root CA as zip file.  Extract the zip, inside there will be a mac folder. Rename the .0 file as .cer .  Leave the .r file alone.
Open up the key chain tool and navigate to the system folder on the upper left, and the certificate repository in the bottom left.  Drag and drop the .cer file there.  Right click the newly imported cer file, click get info, verify it is for the vCenter.  Go to trust drop down, and click trust.

Boom, you can now upload files/iso's, etc. in HTML5 client with self signed certificate.

Comment: Personally I was still unable to upload to https://vSphere.domain.com even after spamming those .cert and .pem files all over just in case I was really missing the documentation. Anyway I ended up going to my VMWare ESXi host which had the datastore attached and then uploaded the file from there. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

1. Type FQDN of Vcenter on browser and open the main page.
2. Download Root CA Certificates from right bottom corner link.
3. Extract downloaded zip file, and install the certificate on your local computer Trusted root Certificate store.
4. Close all browsers and open again, and try.

Follow the detailed step on below article.

https://techkiranangal.blogspot.com/2019/11/vcenter-67-web-client-unable-to-upload.html